# Logical operator sql query going weirdly wrong

Tags: sql, forms, sqlite, blackberry

I am trying to fetch results from my sqlite database by providing a date range.
I have been able to fetch results by providing 3 filters

```
        1. Name (textfield1) 
        2. From (date)(textfield2)
        3. To   (date)(textfield3)
```

I am inserting these field values taken from form into a table temp using following code

```
        Statement statement6 = db.createStatement("INSERT INTO Temp(date,amount_bill,narration) select date,amount,narration from Bills where name=\'"+TextField1.getText()+"\' AND substr(date,7)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(date,1,2) <= substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',7)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',4,2)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',1,2) AND substr(date,7)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(date,1,2) >= substr (\'"+TextField2.getText()+"\',7)||substr (\'"+TextField2.getText()+"\',4,2)||substr (\'"+TextField2.getText()+"\',1,2) ");
                    statement6.prepare();
                    statement6.execute();       
                    statement6.close();
```

Now if i enter the following input in my form for the above filters

```
               1.Ricky
               2.01/02/2012
               3.28/02/2012
```

It fetches date between these date ranges perfectly.
But now i want to insert values that are below and above these 2 date ranges provided.

[image]

I have tried using this code.But it doesnt show up any result.I simply cant figure where the error is

The below code is to find entries having date lesser than 01/02/2012 and greater than 28/02/2012.

```
          Statement statementVII = db.createStatement("INSERT INTO Temp5(date,amount_rec,narration) select date,amount,narration from Bills where name=\'"+TextField1.getText()+"\' AND substr(date,7)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(date,1,2) < substr (\'"+TextField2.getText()+"\',7)||substr (\'"+TextField2.getText()+"\',4,2)||substr (\'"+TextField2.getText()+"\',1,2) AND substr(date,7)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(date,1,2) > substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',7)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',4,2)||substr (\'"+TextField3.getText()+"\',1,2)");
                    statementVII.prepare();
                    statementVII.execute();       
                    statementVII.close();
```

Anyone sound on this,please guide.Thanks.

Comment: Databases are the wrong place to do string manipulation.  Sqllite supports the datetime type - I recommend changing to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use an Or clause together with brackets:

```
WHERE name='....' AND (yourDateField<yourLowerDate OR yourDateField>yourHigherDate)
```

Comment: Thanks so much.Such a silly mistake over the brackets got me pondering so long.Thanks again.

Comment: @techie, if the answer solved your problem, then why don't you mark the answer as accepted? It will help others.